# React with Ant desing Table.set column by useSate header have check box.Check box not working

Tags: reactjs

I want to put a checkbox in the header column where the column uses useState. But the checkbox is not working.but checkBox have update is true

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Button, Checkbox, Form, Input,Space,Table } from "antd";
const App = () => {
 const [checkBox,setCheckBox]=React.useState(false)
 const [columns,setColumns] = React.useState([
     {
       title: 'Name',
       dataIndex: 'name',
       key: 'name',
},
{
  title: ()=>{
    return (
      <>
      <Space>
        age
        <Checkbox onChange={(e)=>setCheckBox(e.target.checked)} 
        checked={checkBox}
        />
      </Space>
      </>
    )
  },
  dataIndex: 'age',
  key: 'age',
},
{
  title: 'Address',
  dataIndex: 'address',
  key: 'address',
}]);

 const dataSource = [
{
  key: '1',
  name: 'Mike',
  age: 32,
  address: '10 Downing Street',
},
{
  key: '2',
  name: 'John',
  age: 42,
  address: '10 Downing Street',
}];

React.useEffect(()=>{
  setColumns(columns.filter((ele)=>ele.dataIndex!=='name'))
 },[])


return (
  <>
  <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />
  </>
   )
 }
 export default App;
```

**can not checked but in useState in update**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWTQJ.png)

you can coppy into this link:[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/grpjto?file=/demo.js:0-1493)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this checkbox issue need to use **state**.

Here is the [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-in-table-header-fhrjdk) with working code.

Answer (score 0):

To implement checkbox at Antd table, you need to add property `rowSelection` at the table

```js
  <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />
```

First addd selectedRowKeys state to keep the information of selected keys

```js
   const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);
```

Then create data & column data

```js
  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
    },
    {
      title: 'Address',
      dataIndex: 'address',
      key: 'address',
    },
  ];

  const dataSource = [
    {
      key: '1',
      name: 'Mike',
      age: 32,
      address: '10 Downing Street',
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      name: 'John',
      age: 42,
      address: '10 Downing Street',
    }
  ];
```

Add row selection const as the input of Table's rowSelection property that contain `onChange: (keys) => setSelectedRowKeys(keys),` that will update the selectedRowKeys state on any checkbox change.

```js
  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys,
    onChange: (keys) => setSelectedRowKeys(keys),
    selections: [
      Table.SELECTION_ALL,
      Table.SELECTION_INVERT,
      Table.SELECTION_NONE,
    ]
  };
```

And here is the complete code:

```js
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table } from 'antd'; 
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
    },
    {
      title: 'Address',
      dataIndex: 'address',
      key: 'address',
    },
  ];

  const dataSource = [
    {
      key: '1',
      name: 'Mike',
      age: 32,
      address: '10 Downing Street',
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      name: 'John',
      age: 42,
      address: '10 Downing Street',
    }
  ];

  // this useEffect is used to watch selection changes and log the values
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedRowKeys)
  }, [selectedRowKeys])

  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys,
    onChange: (keys) => setSelectedRowKeys(keys),
    selections: [
      Table.SELECTION_ALL,
      Table.SELECTION_INVERT,
      Table.SELECTION_NONE,
    ]
  };

  return <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />
}
```